# How to create this shape (quadilateral with rounded corners) in CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, css-shapes

I am building a widget in React Js, and in the design, this image is in the background.

[image: Create thi shape in css]

My problem is the background color is dynamic and the width and height may change according to the devices. I tried using inline SVG(I can control fill color in this way but not the size) and also SVG inside `img` tag (I can control size in this way but not the color), but I cannot control both color and size.

Edit -  inline SVG code snippet -

```
<svg width="360" height="349" viewBox="0 0 300 349" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 20C0 8.9543 8.95431 0 20 0H280C291.046 0 300 8.95431 300 20V187.023C300 194.606 295.711 201.537 288.925 204.921L0 349V20Z" fill="#5795fa"></path></svg>
```

I tried changing that widht, but the svg is created for that particular width, so it's not changing.

It will be great if someone can help me to create this shape using CSS or any other way in which I can control both color and size.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "I tried using inline SVG(I can control fill color in this way but not the size)" You should be able to control size. May you send code snippets with inline svg?

Comment: @Arseniy-II I edited the question (added inline svg code snippet)

Comment: I understand your problem, if i am not wrong then you want something similar to my solution. please have a look on my solution and do let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just remove `width`, `height` and `fill` attributes and use css:**

```css
svg {
    width: 360px;
    fill: #5795fa;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 349" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 20C0 8.9543 8.95431 0 20 0H280C291.046 0 300 8.95431 300 20V187.023C300 194.606 295.711 201.537 288.925 204.921L0 349V20Z"></path></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution

> You can change outer width as to check (Responsive).

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
}

.upper-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0;
}

.lower-box {
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
  height: 110px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="upper-box"></div>
  <div class="lower-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want existing SVG code and use also as responsive, I can also give a solution for the same but firstly please have a look on this CSS solution.

Comment: Yeah, this works. It may help others. But the other one suits my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different idea using pseudo element where you only need to adjust the width/height of the main element to control the size:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:10px 10px 10px 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:lightblue;
  transform:skewY(-25deg);
  transform-origin:left;
  border-bottom-right-radius:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

If you want to control the color from the main element you can consider gradient:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:10px 10px 10px 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  background-size:0 0;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image:inherit;
  transform:skewY(-25deg);
  transform-origin:left;
  border-bottom-right-radius:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-image:linear-gradient(red,red)">

</div>

<div class="box" style="background-image:linear-gradient(green,green)">

</div>
```

Or CSS variables:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:10px 10px 10px 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:var(--c);
  transform:skewY(-25deg);
  transform-origin:left;
  border-bottom-right-radius:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--c:red">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--c:green">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to wrap this **svg** into a block <**div**> element, casue you use the **viewBox** attribute in this **svg** it will grow or shrink proportionaly.

Take a look on this code snap:

```html
<div class="wrap">
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 349" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path class="path" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
        d="M0 20C0 8.9543 8.95431 0 20 0H280C291.046 0 300 8.95431 300 20V187.023C300 194.606 295.711 201.537 288.925 204.921L0 349V20Z"></path>
</svg> 
</div>
```

I remove the *svg*'s **width** and **height** attribute, and removed *path*'s **fill** attribute and assign a class attribute so that you can change wraper's size and *path* color by:

```css
.wrap {
    width: 500px; /* the height will proportionaly grow or shrink complied with the viewBox */
}
.path {
    fill: red; /* specify the color as you wish */
}
```

Here below is the css shap, not perfect but very close to that svg:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #5795fa;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.box::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 30px solid #5795fa;
  border-left: 150px solid #5795fa;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```